# ios - get list of playlists, open single playlist with uuid and get share URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-musickit

I'm struggling a bit with iOS/Apple Music/Playlists.
I have the ability to:

- Create a playlist with a UUID (GUID)
- Get the same playlist with the given UUID
- List all of my playlists

To get a list of my playlists:

```
MPMediaQuery *myPlaylistsQuery = [MPMediaQuery playlistsQuery];
NSArray *playlists = [myPlaylistsQuery collections];

for (MPMediaPlaylist *playlist in playlists) {
    NSLog (@"%@", [playlist valueForProperty: MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName]);
}
```

To get the playlist via the UUID (where `metaData` is empty):

```
[[MPMediaLibrary defaultMediaLibrary] getPlaylistWithUUID:playlistUUID creationMetadata:metaData completionHandler:^(MPMediaPlaylist * _Nullable playlist, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        NSLog (@"%@", [playlist.name]);
      }];
```

### The Problem (Part 1):

I want to be able to list all of my playlists then get one of them ideally with the UUID but that doesn't seem to be returned. I can see a `PersistentID` but that can't be used to retrieve the playlist via the 'get' method.

### The Problem (Part 2):

I also want to be able to retrieve the 'share' link for a given playlist. This doesn't seem to be a way of accessing this at all. Am I right in thinking it isn't available via code?

Comment: P1: why not store the playlist objects in an NSMutableDictionary with the UUID as a key? P2: when sharing a playlist, are you sharing the files or references to the songs etc?